# Unchecked Radio Button Two Cicks

Tags: javascript, html

I need to check the first radio button (value = "option1") by default. But after adding "checked" attributes, the radio button with value "option2" needs two click to get checked. Any idea whats wrong here?
Based on other posts i have included the code in between form tag, i have also tried changing "checked" to 'checked="checked"', tried with different "name" attribute, removing the div around radio button.

This is my code:

**HTML**

```html
            <div class="action">
                <div class="...">{label...}</div>
                <div class="...">
                    <input type="radio" tabindex="0" aria-label={...} name="preview" value="option1" onclick={getPreview} checked></input>
                    <label>{...}</label>
                </div>
                <div class="...">
                    <input type="radio" tabindex="0" aria-label={...} name="preview" value="option2" onclick={getPreview} ></input>
                    <label>{...}</label>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**JS**

```js
 getPreview(event) {
        if(event.target.value == "option1") {
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }
```

But nothing seems to be working.

Comment: firstly that's not how use to close input element use this - `/>`

Comment: I am using LWC framework, bare html and js works fine for me but with LWC framework i still have the same issue. I should probably post this in channel specific to LWC. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You input have some issues with input closing and also with your JS.

This is how you can close input element `/>`

Also, if you are calling `getPrevious` on input click you can use `getPrevious(this)` and get the value of the `onclick` input like this simplified method.

Just run snippet below to see it action.

```js
function getPreview(event) {
  if (event.value == "option1") {
    console.log('option 1 checked')
  } else {
    console.log('option 2 checked')
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="action">
  <div class="...">{label...}</div>
  <div class="...">
    <input type="radio" tabindex="0" aria-label={...} name="preview" value="option1" onclick="getPreview(this)"/>
    <label>{...}</label>
  </div>
  <div class="...">
    <input type="radio" tabindex="0" aria-label={...} name="preview" value="option2" onclick="getPreview(this)" />
    <label>{...}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But it did not work. If i remove the "checked" attribute both the radio buttons get checked on single click.

Comment: @pks its working fine. i have updated my answer and removed `checked`. Run Snippet to see it.